# vb chart second xaxis label offset

Tags: vb.net, charts, label, series

I am creating a VB.Net chart with date/time as the xAxis labels. It is working fine but what I want to do is sync the second label to a even hour boundary. The chart should have the first label as the first date/time in the dataset, but the labels following would then be on a 6 hour (00:00 - 06:00 - 12:00 - 18:00) boundry. I could also live with not having the first axis label as long as the rest were on a 6 (or 12, depending on the length of the data) hour boundary.

Current:

07:00-------13:00-------19:00-------01:00-------07:00-------13:00

What I'm after:

07:00--12:00-------18:00-------00:00-------06:00-------12:00

[Chart as currently produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4yEV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it... sort of.

```
For area As Integer = 0 To numLanes -1
    myArea = New ChartArea("myArea" & area.ToString)
    With myArea
        .BackColor = mySetup.colorPlotBackground ' set from user preferences
        .Area3DStyle.Enable3D = mySetup.is3D  ' set from user preferences
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "g"
        .AxisX.Interval = 1
        .AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days
        .AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0
        .AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours ' Set the X value type of the displayed series to DateTime. 
    End With
    cht.ChartAreas.Add(myArea)
```

Produces the attached chart.

[Slightly Improved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TuAV.png)